# R Shiny - Using MathJax with tippy.js

Tags: r, shiny, tippyjs

The app below has a tooltip that contains a mathematical expression and I was wondering if it was possible to render the expression in MathJax?

Here is the app:

```
library(shiny)
library(tippy)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tippyOutput('math')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$math = renderTippy({

      tippy("Click me!", 
            tooltip = HTML(as.character(withMathJax('$$\\frac{1}{\\pi\\gamma\\,\\left[1 +
               \\left(\\frac{x-x_0}{\\gamma}\\right)^2\\right]}\\!$$'))))


    })
  }
)
```

The [documentation](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v5/html-content/#string) for tippy.js says that it is possible to include HTML content inside a tooltip but I can't seem to get the math expression to render correctly.

The output of `withMathJax()` is a list of length 3: a head tag, a character string containing the math expression and a script tag. I tried to convert it to a single character string by wrapping it in `HTML(as.character(...))` but it doesn't work.

---

If I render the MathJax expression on its own (without a tippy) as follows:

```
output$trial = renderUI({
      withMathJax('$$\\frac{1}{\\pi\\gamma\\,\\left[1 +
               \\left(\\frac{x-x_0}{\\gamma}\\right)^2\\right]}\\!$$')
    })
```

...the output looks like this:

[image]

But the output of `renderTippy` looks very different:

[image]

For example, the `<span class="MathJax_Preview" style="color: inherit; display: none;"></span>` and `<div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;">...</div>` nodes are missing.

Is this due to the `if (window.MathJax) MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);` not running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not seem possible. Here is a way to get the math expression using **KaTeX**:

```
library(shiny)
library(tippy)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel="stylesheet", 
                href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/katex.min.css", 
                integrity="sha384-dbVIfZGuN1Yq7/1Ocstc1lUEm+AT+/rCkibIcC/OmWo5f0EA48Vf8CytHzGrSwbQ",
                crossorigin="anonymous"),
      HTML('<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-2BKqo+exmr9su6dir+qCw08N2ZKRucY4PrGQPPWU1A7FtlCGjmEGFqXCv5nyM5Ij" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>'),
      HTML('<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-kWPLUVMOks5AQFrykwIup5lo0m3iMkkHrD0uJ4H5cjeGihAutqP0yW0J6dpFiVkI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>'),
      HTML('
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#math").on("mouseover", function(){
          setTimeout(function(){renderMathInElement(document.body, {delimiters: [{left: "$", right: "$", display: true}]});},0);
        })
      });
    </script>')
    ),
    tippyOutput('math'),
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    output$math = renderTippy({

      tippy('Click me!', 
            tooltip = '$\\frac{1}{\\pi\\gamma\\,\\left[1 + \\left(\\dfrac{x-x_0}{\\gamma}\\right)^2\\right]}\\!$')

    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Stéphane, I was not aware of KaTex. Would it please be possible to explain why MathJax doesn't work here? I have edited my question to illustrate the differences in the DOM between rendering withMathJax inside `renderTippy` vs `renderUI`.